# how to keep asp.net core web api app always ON to avoid cold/idle issue hosted in AKS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-aks, azure-appservice

I have bunch of asp.net core web api apps running in AKS and below is the observation:

- First api request of the day completes in 5009ms.

[image]

- Subsequent request within few seconds completes in 367ms

[image]

**After 20 minutes When again I making API call,**

- First call took again 2590ms, why? Is this cold start behavior? how to avoid it?

[image]

- Subsequent calls completes in 372ms

[image]

I came to know we have some solution for it in App Service where I can make service ALWAYS ON to avoid delay in API response if call makes after idle time.

Question is, what are solution for AKS deployed web api's? Will Kubernetes liveness prob will help here (so far I haven't used it)?

Comment: add a periodic ping/health check.

Comment: Thanks @ Daniel A. White. Could you please share some blog, code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always have a liveness probe setup, it is the only way that Kubernetes knows that your container hasn't died.

If you call e.g. api/version on the liveness probe or if you have external dependencies, you could chain those into an api/healthcheck and then you just configure your deployment to this check.

[Configure liveness, readiness and startup probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

Comment: Thanks @Luke Briner. Thinking the same. Do u have any good blog/link for asp.net core web API implementation, please share. appreciate.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Don't you already have the implementation? If you mean the YAML, it is in the link I put on the answer.

Comment: Yes. I have not done anything for my web api application. How to implement it for asp.net core 3.1/5 web api apps?